# Как обратиться к внешней локальной переменной?

Tags: c++

Я знаю, что можно обратиться к глобальной переменной таким способом:

```
int i = 10;
int main() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int i = ::i; i < 10; i++)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Можно ли сделать то же самое, но для внешней локальной?

Comment: Что такое внешняя локальная переменная? Нет ли здесь конфузии?

Comment: @MBo Я имею ввиду переменную, которую инициализировали в области видимости на 1 уровень выше. В данном случае это переменная i во внешнем цикле for.

Comment: Как бы выразиться... Представим на минуту, что это возможно. И что это даст, кроме полного запутывания?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Имя локальной переменной внешнего блока будет перекрываться переменной внутреннего блока. Какого-то специального синтаксиса (вроде разрешения области видимости `::` для доступа к именам из других пространств имён) не существует.

Можно, конечно, завести дополнительную ссылочную переменную, через которую будет доступ. Но выглядит это странно, проще сразу дать разные имена:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   auto& r = i;
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       // i из внешнего цикла доступна через r
```

Вообще, практика использования одинаковых локальных имён с сокрытием на разных уровнях достаточно порочна, лучше этого избегать, чтобы не порождать ситуации, когда думаешь, что во внутреннем блоке работаешь со внешней переменной. Например:

```
int ret = 0;         // внешний уровень (O)
// ...
{
   int ret = 100500; // внутренний уровень (I)
   // ...
   ret = 42;         // хочешь изменить переменную внешнего уровня (R)
   // ...
}
return ret;
```

Ситуация, описанная выше, могла родиться по такой схеме:

1. Написали функцию без переменной `ret` внутреннего блока (I). В (R) происходит изменение переменной уровня (O). Всё ок.
2. Кто-то другой (и ты сам через пару месяцев) добавил переменную `ret` во внутренний блок (I) для исключительно локального использования в блоке (например, отладить какую-то функцию). И теперь в (R) происходит изменение другой переменной. Фейл.

Ошибки такого рода не всегда просто заметить, обычно к ним приводит использование простых и популярных имён типа (`i`, `ret`, `var`, `enabled` ... ). К счастью, для обнаружения подобных ситуаций в компиляторах есть соответствующие опции, порождающие предупреждение, например, `-Wshadow` для gcc.

Answer (score 0):

Если ты имеешь ввиду `int i = 10;` после того как ты её дважды переобъявил, нет! Конечно нельзя! Но в твоём примере ты использовал root namespace.

```cpp
namespace {
    int i = 10;
}

// Таким образом ::i `int(10)` будет доступна
::i

namespace myNamespace {
  int i = 10;
}

myNamespace::i
```

В принципе таким образом весь `namespace std { ... }` описан. Как основные методы/переменные C++.